# Не работают фильтры в primefaces 8.0 в таблице при включенной виртуализации строк

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, datatable, primefaces

Использую Primefaces 8.0.
Есть таблица с замороженными столбцами + включены фильтры на столбцах в замороженной части и скроллируемой + включена виртуализация строк.
Код таблицы:

```
<p:commandLink partialSubmit="true" process="@this" action="#{controller.loadCars}"  update=":form:tab1">
  <h:outputText value="Submit"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

```
<h:form id="form">                                     

<p:dataTable
                                       id="tab1"
                                       scrollable="true"
                                       scrollHeight="350"
                                       scrollWidth="900"
                                       frozenColumns="2"
                                       var="car"
                                       scrollRows="5"
                                       virtualScroll="true"
                                       lazy="true"
                                       rows="5"
                                       rowIndexVar="#"
                                       value="#{model.cars}"
                                       widgetVar="carsTable"
                                       emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria"
                                       filteredValue="#{filtePR8Model.filteredCars}">

                                 <p:ajax event="filter"  />


                                 <p:columnGroup groupRow="true" type="frozenHeader" >

                                    <p:row>
                                       <p:column field="1" headerText="Id"  filterBy="#{car.id}" filterMatchMode="contains"  >
                                          <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                                                       onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                                          </p:inputText>
                                       </p:column>
                                       <p:column field="2" headerText="Color" filterBy="#{car.color}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                                          <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                                                       onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                                          </p:inputText>

                                       </p:column>


                                    </p:row>
                                 </p:columnGroup>
                                 <p:columnGroup groupRow="true" type="scrollableHeader">

                                    <p:row>
                                       <p:column headerText="Id" width="100"/>

                                       <p:column field="4" headerText="Year" filterBy="#{car.year}" filterable="true" filterMatchMode="contains" width="100">
                                          <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                                                       onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                                          </p:inputText>
                                       </p:column>

                                       <p:column headerText="Brand" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Color" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Id" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Year" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Brand" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Color" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Id" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Year" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column headerText="Brand" width="100"/>
                                       <p:column field="3" sortBy="#{car.color}" filterBy="#{car.color}" headerText="Color2" filterMatchMode="contains" width="100" >
                                          <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                                                       onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                                                       onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                                          </p:inputText>
                                       </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                 </p:columnGroup>

                                 <p:column headerText="Id" >
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}"/>
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Color" >
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Id">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Year">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Brand">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Color">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Id">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Year">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Brand">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Color">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Id">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Year">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Brand">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column headerText="Color">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                                 </p:column>

                                 <p:column groupRow="true" headerText="Color2" >
                                    <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
                                 </p:column>

                              </p:dataTable>


</h:form>
```

Контроллер

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Model model;


    public void loadCars(){
        model.getCars().clear();
        List<Car> tempCars = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
            tempCars.add(new Car( UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8), model.getBrands().get((int)(Math.random() * 10)), String.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1960)), model.getColors().get((int) (Math.random() * 10)), (int) (Math.random() * 100000), (Math.random() > 0.5) ? true: false ));
        }
        model.getCars().addAll(tempCars);
    }

}
```

Модель

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Data;

@Named
@SessionScoped
@Data
public class Model implements Serializable {

    Model(){

        colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("Black");
        colors.add("White");
        colors.add("Green");
        colors.add("Red");
        colors.add("Blue");
        colors.add("Orange");
        colors.add("Silver");
        colors.add("Yellow");
        colors.add("Brown");
        colors.add("Maroon");

        brands = new ArrayList<>();
        brands.add("BMW");
        brands.add("Mercedes");
        brands.add("Volvo");
        brands.add("Audi");
        brands.add("Renault");
        brands.add("Fiat");
        brands.add("Volkswagen");
        brands.add("Honda");
        brands.add("Jaguar");
        brands.add("Ford");
    }

    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Car> filteredCars;

    private List<String> colors;

    private List<String> brands;

}
```

Объект

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

    public String id;
    public String brand;
    public String year;
    public String color;
    public int price;
    public boolean sold;

    public Car() {}

    public Car(String id, String brand, String year, String color) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.year = year;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Car(String id, String brand, String year, String color, int price, boolean sold) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.year = year;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isSold() {
        return sold;
    }
    public void setSold(boolean sold) {
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + (this.id != null ? this.id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Car other = (Car) obj;
        if ((this.id == null) ? (other.id != null) : !this.id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

При фильтрации данных в таблицы возникает ошибка JS от библиотеки primefaces.

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "children", b.bodyTable is undefined
    oncomplete http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    v http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    jQuery 6
    send http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    offer http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    handle http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    ab http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/ line 2 > injectedScript:1
    callBehavior http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:22
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    filterTimeout http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    setTimeout handler*bindFilterEvent/< http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    jQuery 2
components.js.xhtml:12:31834
    oncomplete http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    v http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    jQuery 6
    send http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    offer http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    handle http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    ab http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/ line 2 > injectedScript:1
    callBehavior http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:22
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    filterTimeout http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    (Асинхронный: setTimeout handler)
    bindFilterEvent http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    jQuery 2
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Попробовал воспроизвести представленный код, получилось что-то совсем непонятное. Таблица выглядит "сломанной", причём настолько, что даже строки с данными не отображаются. Если у Вас так же, то сначала стоило бы сделать что-то минимально работающее, и уже после добавлять и проверять фильтры. Если у Вас всё ОК (кроме фильтров), то нужен код, который позволит воспроизвести ситуацию в отрыве от остальных частей проекта, без зависимостей

Comment: Поправил код и проверил. Фильтры в таблице работают стабильно, но стоит включить виртуализацию строк, возникает ошибка в JS primefeces..

Comment: Работоспособности таблицы добиться не удалось. Получившаяся комбинация столбцов - непонятная. Попробуйте для начала сделать обычные, "плоские", столбцы, без группировок. Бывает, что неправильное формирование групп столбцов приводит к непредвиденным ошибкам. Если виртуализация строк при этом перестанет приводит к сбоям, то постепенно начните применять группировки столбцов, проверяя виртуализацию на каждом шагу - возможно, так получиться определить причину сбоя.

Comment: Если обобщенно.. Виртуализация строк и фильтры не работают в связке на любом типе таблицы, не обязательно из моего приведенного кода, стоит отключить фильтры или виртуализацию то работает то что включено. Я пытаюсь понять как заставить работать их вместе.